# How to send ELM327 command via USB and fetch the answer?

Tags: command-line, usb

can someone help me please, how to send an ELM327 command to my OBDII dongle, connected via USB and fetch the answer in a $Var?

Kris Occhipinti made a great video on YouTube, where he show how to do this by the `screen` command. "ELM327 USB OBD2 Linux Videos Part #2"

But I am trying to use this data in a script, whether Python or Bash.

Something like

```
echo "01 01" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

where the answer of the USB device should be in $VAR

Answer (score 0):

There is a python library called [python-OBD](https://python-obd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that can do most of this for you, if you don't want to build it from scratch. If you would prefer not to use a premade library, [here is a quick tutorial](http://blog.brianhemeryck.me/how-to-interface-with-your-cars-ecu-through-obd2-and-python/) on how to do it with pyserial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AT commands.
You may use Python Serial Library.
This might help - https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/AppNote07.pdf

Comment: Hello. A link only answer is not considered an answer. What about later when that link does not work?